# How to add values to objects similar to push(array) using forEach

Tags: angular, object, foreach

I'm currently struggling to add some numbers to an object like we do for arrays using push().

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$scope.order = [
  {sequenceNumber:1},
  {sequenceNumber:2},
  {sequenceNumber:3}  
];
```

And i'm using a forEach method to add the numbers to an object "newOrder"

```
var newOrder = {};

angular.forEach($scope.order, function(orderValue) {
  newOrder = orderValue.sequenceNumber;
});
```

However...this doesnt return the result that i want

I want "newOrder" to look like this:

```
var newOrder = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3
};
```

Value = position of the array

Key = sequenceNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` in this case, like so:

```
var newOrder = $scope.order.reduce(function(acc, item, index) {
  acc[item.sequenceNumber] = index;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Or shorter equivalent:

```
var newOrder = $scope.order.reduce((acc, {sequenceNumber}, index) => {
  acc[sequenceNumber] = index;
  return acc;
}, {});
```